# Druapal Glossary Mode not showing in contextual filters

Tags: views

I dont see the glossary mode  when adding arguments in contextual filters.

But on other views I am able to set the glossary mode.

Comment: I am having this problem when I create views on users. I dont see the glossary mode option in the contextual filters. I am using civicrm contact lastname us the argument to filter.

Comment: I found this problem with civicrm fields not showing the glossary mode.. I found this link http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=17749.0 .. but it is not working to me

Comment: Sorry It is working to me know..